# Webpack doesn't work with 'module' field of in-direct dependencies

Tags: webpack, module

I have two modules which have only `module` field (points to an `esm` bundle file) in their `package.json`, and have no `main` field.

`module2` uses `module1`, and I also created a demo project uses `module2`.

Since they both have `module` field, I specify the `resolve.mainFields` in the webpack config file in the demo project:

```
resolve: {
  mainFields: ['module']
}
```

but when I run `webpack` in the demo project, only `module2` is resolved correctly, and webpack can't find the bundle file of `module1`.

I created a demo project with complete code for this issue, please see: 
https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-webpack-uses-esm-modules-demo/tree/issue

Hope to know where is wrong and make them work, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem is the file name. The bundle name was `.mjs`, and I changed it to `.something.js`, it's OK now.